# Need cases of *scientistic* fallacies in 19th century anthropological/ethnological studies of Native Americans

Tags: philosophy-of-science, anthropology

I'm looking for primary sources in which the author(s) commit [scientistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientism) fallacies when speaking about Native Americans.

I'm working my way through S.G. Morton's *Crania Americana*, which is close, but the appendix in this, regarding physiognomy, by George Combe is even closer.

Could anyone tell me any more examples of where a border-crossing violation (Peterson, *Demarcation and the Scientistic Fallacy*), that is to say when someone tries to expand their field of science onto something that isn't actually covered by it, occurs.

Thanks :)

Comment: You might find some useful discussions here and there in "1491," Charles Mann

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look :)